# Use java regex to find integer in a string

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I want to find all numbers in a string. The number will have format {number}, {+number}, {-number}, for example: 123, +456, -789.

I have regex: `(\+|\-)?[0-9]+(?![A-Za-z])`

And string test is: `123 +234 -345 456 - + abc a+78 sdf-sdf +1abc -3sbc`

It will print:

```
123
+234
-345
456
+78
```

**+78** is wrong result because **+78** in **a+78** is not number.

Please help me fix the regex pattern to find only numbers.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Your pattern will also match in `+123(` Instead, you can use whitespace boundaries like `(?!\S)` and `(?<!\S)` like `(?<!\S)[+-]?[0-9]+(?!\S)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be to find numbers which are surrounded on both sides by either whitespace, or the start/end of the string.  We can use the following pattern:

```
(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+(?!\S)
```

Java code:

```java
String input = "123 +234 -345 456 - + abc a+78 sdf-sdf +1abc -3sbc";
String pattern = "(?<!\\S)[+-]?\\d+(?!\\S)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(matches);  // [123, +234, -345, 456]
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `(?<!\S)` assert that what precedes be either whitespace or the start of the input
- `[+-]?` match optional leading +/-
- `\d+` match an integer number
- `(?!\S)` assert that what follows be either whitespace or the end of the input

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage programming to make the regex bit simpler. So, you can split the string by space and try to match the pattern for each split value instead of matching the whole input.

The regex will be:

1. `^[-+]?` - It may start with + or -
2. `[0-9]+$` - It is then followed by number till the end

So, the final regex is: `^[-+]?[0-9]+$`

Simple java code will be:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
String[] arr= "123 +234 -345 456 - + abc a+78 sdf-sdf +1abc -3sbc".split(" ");
for(String elem:arr){
    String pattern = "^[-+]?[0-9]+$";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(elem);
    if(m.find()){
       result.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, you can also use positive look-arounds.

```
(?<=^|\s)[+-]?\d+(?=\s|$)
```

Here is an example.

```java
String string = "123 +234 -345 456 - + abc a+78 sdf-sdf +1abc -3sbc";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)[+-]?\\d+(?=\\s|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Output

```
123
+234
-345
456
```

Comment: your regex pattern will miss **456**

Comment: @Hoang, you're right, thanks.  I changed my answer.